# The size of the photos on the apps

Tags: flutter-layout

I want to add some photos on my app on screens and icons. How i can finde out, what is the best size of the photo for screens or icons.
I tried some photos, but they don't look well.

Comment: Use principles of Responsive :
The ratio of the size of the images and icons in relation to the total size of the screen.

Comment: ok. but in which size should i take the photo? 1024 pix? 700 pix @hossamo Bin Aref

Comment: You can use different image sizes according to the customer's screen size while maintaining the image quality.

Or use the same image with its inclusion in the display, for example, (Fit) Property in Container():

fit: BoxFit.fill